# height: 100% для картинок во flex-контейнере

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Решил сверстать адаптивную галерею картинок на flexbox. При этом столкнулся с неприятным багом - блоки с картинками отказываются правильно растягиваться по высоте и занимать всю площадь.

Решить это можно добавлением к img `height:100%` тогда все работает отлично  только в Chrome и firefox , но не в Safari.

Вопрос: как заставить блоки с картинками растягиваться правильно по высоте во все браузерах?

[Пример на Codepen](https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/WOyGRN?editors=0100)

[image: Кривие блоки]

Comment: а пример кода можно?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Пример на Codepen, смотри ниже

Comment: ну да но все это можно и здесь сделать в вопросе, что бы наглядно было

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно решить проблему таким способом: нужно присвоить высоту `.grid__item` к `img`

```
  $('.grid__item').each(function (i,v){
          var h = $(v).height();
          $(v).find('img').height(h);
      });
```